# R self-referring ifelse statement in Data Frame

Tags: r

I have an ifelse statement in R, that looks something like:

```
val<-rnorm(500,1)
df<-data.frame(val)
df['X']<-NA
df[1,'X']<-0
df['X']<-ifelse(is.na(df$X),ifelse(df$val>0,c(0,df$X[-length(df$X)])+1,df$val),df$X)
df
row    val,        x
1      0.515...    0
2      1.832...    1
3     -0.160...   -0.160...
4      2.110...    NA
```

Of course in the example above, as I write it out, I realise a small bug where I would want it to reset to 0, rather than take `df$val` as the value, but I dont think that's too important for the bug at hand?

This works correctly for the 2nd row but breaks on the third. The 1st Else statement, `df$val`, works fine but it doesnt seem to recursively? If I had to naively guess, when I am using `df$X` in the `ifelse` statement, it is taking a copy of `df$X` and not self-referring?

If so, how do I get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sure. I want the value X to increment every time we have a val > 0, and if it is less than 0, we apply some other logic. In fact in my problem, X doesn't increment by 1, but instead, a third column df['Z'], but I think once I understand how to do the increment by 1, it will increment by the 'Z' quite easily. This is a bit of an analogy to my problem, so if this doesnt work I may have to delve into further depth

Comment: Your last line is missing a closing bracket and gives an error even if adding the bracket. If you don't either state the full logic or give the expected output, it will be very hard to help.

Comment: Effectively I have a nested ifelse statement. `IF(is.na(number),IFELSE(val>0, do_one_thing_based_on_previous_value,do_another_thing_based_on_previous_value),current_value)`

Comment: My apologies, code amended for a missing bracket on the c(0...)statement

Comment: You are right in thinking that the variable is not self-referring. You very likely need to change your strategy. However, the real logic really matters in the way you could reach your goal.

Comment: Is there any way for me to get around this?

Comment: I solved this by using a for loop. I know that's really bad practise, but googling around, I couldnt see any way of solving the Fibonacci sequence without a for loop! (Effectively the problem)